# Keep same scale while rotating

Tags: rotation, scale, blender

I want to keep scale when i rotate verticles. But it is getting smaller after rotation. Picture 3 and 4:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can i keep it same size ?

Comment: I am trying 45 degree y-axis.

Comment: Circle size remains the same. You can cut your cylinder with a knife, knife project, or boolean operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotate is the wrong tool, if you look directly at the circular face after rotating it will remain circular, where the result you are after will become an oval.

The tool you want is called [shear](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html), which will move the top vertices the opposite way to the bottom vertices without altering the height. You can find shear in *Mesh->Transform->Shear* or the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>. The shear tool transforms based on the view so you will want to be in side view when you use it.

Another option would be to use the [knife tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html) to cut a line through your tube.

You can also position a plane over the tube and use [intersect (Knife)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#intersect).